# Saving images as Blobs with TypeORM Cordova database

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, typeorm

**Synopsis**
My images don't get correctly saved to my Cordova SQLite database. I'm using typeorm. The data (Uint8Array) gets transformed to string, such that I'm not able to decode it back again.

**Long version**
 
I save the following Uint8Array to my Cordova SQLite database via typeorm:

```
Uint8Array(4144617) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 255, 219,...]
```

and what I get back out again is of type string:

```
���� JFIF      �� C �� C...
```

When I convert this via `Buffer.from(image)` to a Uint8Array it has nearly doubled its size:

```
Uint8Array(7723287) [239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 
189, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 239, 191, 189, 239, 
191, 189, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,...]
```

The above string is the same Uint8Array representation as if I would print it out as string to console. I tried different encodings (utf8, ascii, windows-1253, utf-16le) to decode this string into an Uint8Array back, but all produce more then there was before.
The log message for inserts looks just fine:

```
query:  INSERT INTO someEntity (id, name, created, createdby, 
        lastchangedby, lastchanged, status, graphic) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
        -- PARAMETERS: ["1","some name","2018-05-28T22:46:38.896Z","username","username",
        "2018-05-28T22:46:38.896Z","1",
        {"type":"Buffer","data":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,255,219,...]]
```

But the result in the database is always a string, no matter which method I use:

- `connection.manager.query("INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)", [parameters...])`
- `connection.manager.save(entity)`
- `connection.manager.createQueryBuilder().insert().into(entity).values({parameters...}).execute()`

I pulled the database from my Android device and inspected it with DB Browser for SQLite to verify, that the issue is lying in insert statement and not in select.

In my entity the image field is defined as follows:

```
@Column("blob",{ 
    nullable:true,
    name:"graphic"
})
graphic: Buffer;
```

I'm struggling with this for 2 weeks and tried several different approaches.

**Question**
So my questions condense to: Is there any trick or workaround to save images/files as true blobs/byte array in the database or is there a way to convert the saved string back to a displayable image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have you been able to convert back to image now?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :/

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get this to work in sqljs with typeorm. Here's the method to convert to base64 string so as to display the buffer data coming from the database.

```
 BufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var byte = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var byteLen = byte.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < byteLen; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( byte[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

Then find a way to display the base64 string. In my case, all i needed to do is set a image prefix and then pass the method along. Here's a sample

```
<img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+BufferToBase64(graphic)" />
```

The key thing is converting the byte[]  to base64. Cheers.

Comment: hey, i have kinda the same problem. i load an image from an external server and the result of the request is a valid Blob object which i can use like a charm. But after loading it from the db its just an object Object and after debugging i found out, that the query which saves the Blob seems to only save the string of the blob e.g. "{"size": 123, "type":"image/png"}. so there is something fishy in the update.. also tried other stuff instead of blob like buffer, arraybuffer.. so how did you saved the blob? i dont want to use base64 cause why? you can use Blobs directly as source Url